# Powershell Query Multiple Computers for Public IP Address not Working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to query multiple computer for their public IP address. If I use script 1, I am only able to query one computer at a time and save the output to a file. If I use text file with multiple computernames, only 1 or 2 computers get queried. ( I am able to query all computers if I do 1 by 1.)

I then added try,catch in script 2 to catch any non-responding computers but that script outputs nothing. Ideally, I would like to query multiple computers and catch any non responding computers but script 2 wont work.

*Script 1*

```
$computers= Get-Content .\hostnames.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {

$computerSystem = (get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $computer).name 

$IP=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://smart-ip.net/myip" -UseBasicParsing).content }  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } 

$computerSystem, $ip | out-file .\output2.csv -Append
```

*Script 2*

```
$computernames =  Get-Content .\hostnames.txt
$NotRespondingLog = ".\notresponding.log" 

$data = ForEach ($Computer in $computernames) {
try{

$computerSystem = (get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $computer).name 

$IP=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {

(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://smart-ip.net/myip" -UseBasicParsing ).content }  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

} catch{
    $Computer | Out-File -FilePath $NotRespondingLog -Append -Encoding UTF8
        continue    } }

$data | out-file ".\output2.csv" -Append
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code isn't emitting anything to return to your pipeline or your text file.  I'd advise we should re-write this a bit to be easier to understand.

If you wonder why your `try/catch` isn't being evaluated, this is because on your `Invoke-WebRequest` command you have `-ErrorActionPreference` set as `SilentlyContinue`.  This directly tells PowerShell that we do not want to evaluate a catch block or alert when an error occurs.

Here I've rewritten your code a bit for clarity, and added a step or two to emit the objects back out, that's what the lines with the single `$thisPC` 
 commands do.  Whether inside of the try block, or the catch block, we simply create a new PowerShell objects, map the properties, then emit it to the console and add it to a track list called `$ComputerList`.  This is a very common pattern you'll see in enterprise ready scripts..

```
$computernames =  'SomePC123','SomePC234','OfflinePC'

$ComputerList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

ForEach ($Computer in $computernames) {
    try{
        $computerName = (get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $computer).name 
        $IP= Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
            (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://smart-ip.net/myip" -UseBasicParsing ).content -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        $thisPC = [psCustomObject]@{Name=$computerName;IP=$IP}
        $thisPC 
        $ComputerList.Add($thisPC) | Out-Null
    } 
    catch{
        $thisPC = [psCustomObject]@{Name=$Computer;IP='Not Responding'}
        $thisPC
        $ComputerList.Add($thisPC) | Out-Null
    } 
}

$ComputerList | out-file ".\output2.csv" -Append
```

Here's the output of it:

```
Name      IP             
----      --             
SomePC234 149.178.121.237
OfflinePC Not Responding 
SomePC123 48.40.234.122
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and  I also understand your explanation. However, The Output on my end is showing like   SomePC234 149.178.121.2...

Why the ... ?

Comment: can you please check? why the 3 dots?

Comment: When you finish running it, check the value of `$thisPC` in the console, it's possible the three dots appear because of the web site?

Comment: The website shows correct value. checking $thisPC shows the 3 dots. when I do $thisPC | ft -wrap it shows me full IP address. However, when exported to csv, it again shows 3 dots. Setting $FormatEnumerationLimit=-1 did nothing aswell :(

Comment: Ok i added $ComputerList | ft -Wrap  in the end and it shows full values. I just need to have IP address in separate column and were done!

Comment: If you're sending output to Format-Table, I would recommend you do not do this.  The `Format` commands strips properties from your input items and converts into a character stream to send to the console. This isn't very useful.  If you're intending to output data to use elsewhere or in a report, I'd recommend using `Export-CSV` or `ConvertTo-Json` instead.

Comment: yes you are right! I used   $ComputerList  |  export-csv ".\Public&LocalIP.csv" -Append. I also edited it a bit to include local IP info aswell!